# EXPO EAS Build Crashing In Test Flight But Working In EXPO GO App

Tags: react-native, expo, testflight, eas

I've uploaded my EXPO App to App Store Connect for iOS, using the prompt;

```
eas build -p ios --auto-submit
```

Everything has uploaded to App Store Connect and it's available in Test Flight, launches, shows the splash screen then goes to the initial screen. However, when I click on anything it crashes immediately. Despite the fact that;

1. The app does not crash within the EXPO GO App
2. The app does not crash on a physical device
3. Running `npx expo install --check` returns "Dependencies are up to date" in the Terminal (I suspected it could be a dependency issue)
4. The splash screen loads and then it goes to the initial route in the app. (so some functionality is working)

Can anyone shed some light on what my issues would be?

I have already done the following;

- Uninstalled and reinstalled Test Flight App
- Uploading another Build number

I've added my package.json, app.json & eas.json files.

### package.json

```
{
  "name": "XXXXXXXXXX",
  "main": "expo-router/entry",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "test": "jest --watchAll"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^13.0.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.18.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.2",
    "expo": "~49.0.7",
    "expo-font": "~11.4.0",
    "expo-image": "~1.3.2",
    "expo-linking": "~5.0.2",
    "expo-router": "2.0.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.20.5",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "expo-system-ui": "~2.4.0",
    "expo-web-browser": "~12.3.2",
    "firebase": "^10.2.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.4",
    "react-native-maps": "^1.7.1",
    "react-native-remix-icon": "^0.4.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.6.3",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.22.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.6",
    "react-native-webview": "13.2.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@types/react": "~18.2.14",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.72.2",
    "jest": "^29.2.1",
    "jest-expo": "~49.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "^5.1.3"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "react-refresh": "~0.14.0"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "react-refresh": "~0.14.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

### app.json

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "XXXXXXXXXX",
    "slug": "XXXXXXXXXX",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/images/icon.png",
    "scheme": "myapp",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "automatic",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/images/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": ["**/*"],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": false,
      "buildNumber": "2",
      "bundleIdentifier": "XXX.XXXXXXXXXX.XXXXXXXXXX"
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/images/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
      }
    },
    "web": {
      "bundler": "metro",
      "output": "static",
      "favicon": "./assets/images/favicon.png"
    },
    "plugins": ["expo-router"],
    "experiments": {
      "typedRoutes": true
    },
    "extra": {
      "router": {
        "origin": false
      },
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "9c60bbf3-702e-406c-83a3-09a5f27217ea"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### eas.json

```
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 4.1.2"
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "preview": {
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "production": {}
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {}
  }
}
```